# Array to String Conversion Error: How to solve this error in PHP, I have provided the control flow of code

Tags: php

I am getting error after saving sales and error is occurring in update product function, this function is working fine when i am updating product, but when i try to update product using edit-sales it is giving me this error.

1. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bquI.png)
2. [Code where error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrWIl.png)

**Picture 1 is what error i am getting after saving the edited sales..
picture 2 is code where error is occurring....**

This is controller.sales ( which is calling model.edit-sales)

```
static public function ctrEditSale(){

    if(isset($_POST["editSale"])){

        /*=============================================
        FORMAT PRODUCTS AND CUSTOMERS TABLES
        =============================================*/
        $table = "sales";

        $item = "code";
        $value = $_POST["editSale"];

        $getSale = ModelSales::mdlShowSales($table, $item, $value);

        /*=============================================
        CHECK IF THERE'S ANY EDITED SALE
        =============================================*/


        if($_POST["productsList"] == ""){

            $productsList = $getSale["products"];
            $productChange = false;


        }else{

            $productsList = $_POST["productsList"];
            $productChange = true;
        }

        if($productChange){

            $products =  json_decode($getSale["products"], true);

            $totalPurchasedProducts = array();

            foreach ($products as $key => $value) {             

                array_push($totalPurchasedProducts, $value["quantity"]);    

                $tableProducts = "products";

                $item = "id";
                $value1 = $value["id"];
                $order = "id";

                $getProduct = ProductsModel::mdlShowProducts($tableProducts, $item, $value1, $order);                   

                $item1a = "sales";
                $value1a = $getProduct["sales"] - $value["quantity"];

                $newSales = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts, $item1a, $value1a, $value);

                $item1b = "stock";
                $value1b = $value["quantity"] + $getProduct["stock"];

                $stockNew = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts, $item1b, $value1b, $value);

            }

            $tableCustomers = "customers";

            $itemCustomer = "id";
            $valueCustomer = $_POST["selectCustomer"];

            $getCustomer = ModelCustomers::mdlShowCustomers($tableCustomers, $itemCustomer, $valueCustomer);

            $item1a = "purchases";
            $value1a = $getCustomer["purchases"] - array_sum($totalPurchasedProducts);

            $customerPurchases = ModelCustomers::mdlUpdateCustomer($tableCustomers, $item1a, $value1a, $valueCustomer);

            /*=============================================
            UPDATE THE CUSTOMER'S PURCHASES AND REDUCE THE STOCK AND INCREMENT PRODUCT SALES
            =============================================*/

            $productsList_2 = json_decode($productsList, true);

            $totalPurchasedProducts_2 = array();

            foreach ($productsList_2 as $key => $value) {

                array_push($totalPurchasedProducts_2, $value["quantity"]);
                
                $tableProducts_2 = "products";

                $item_2 = "id";
                $value_2 = $value["id"];
                $order = "id";

                $getProduct_2 = ProductsModel::mdlShowProducts($tableProducts_2, $item_2, $value_2, $order);

                $item1a_2 = "sales";
                $value1a_2 = $value["quantity"] + $getProduct_2["sales"];

                $newSales_2 = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts_2, $item1a_2, $value1a_2, $value_2);

                $item1b_2 = "stock";
                $value1b_2 = $getProduct_2["stock"] - $value["quantity"];

                $newStock_2 = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts_2, $item1b_2, $value1b_2, $value_2);

            }

            $tableCustomers_2 = "customers";

            $item_2 = "id";
            $value_2 = $_POST["selectCustomer"];

            $getCustomer_2 = ModelCustomers::mdlShowCustomers($tableCustomers_2, $item_2, $value_2);

            $item1a_2 = "purchases";
            $value1a_2 = array_sum($totalPurchasedProducts_2) + $getCustomer_2["purchases"];

            $customerPurchases_2 = ModelCustomers::mdlUpdateCustomer($tableCustomers_2, $item1a_2, $value1a_2, $value_2);

            $item1b_2 = "lastPurchase";

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $hour = date('H:i:s');
            $value1b_2 = $date.' '.$hour;

            $dateCustomer_2 = ModelCustomers::mdlUpdateCustomer($tableCustomers_2, $item1b_2, $value1b_2, $value_2);

        }

        /*=============================================
        SAVE PURCHASE CHANGES
        =============================================*/ 

        $data = array("idSeller"=>$_POST["idSeller"],
                       "idCustomer"=>$_POST["selectCustomer"],
                       "code"=>$_POST["editSale"],
                       "products"=>$productsList,
                       "tax"=>$_POST["newTaxPrice"],
                       "netPrice"=>$_POST["newNetPrice"],
                       "totalPrice"=>$_POST["saleTotal"],
                       "paymentMethod"=>$_POST["listPaymentMethod"]);


        $answer = ModelSales::mdleditSale($table, $data);

        if($answer == "ok"){

            echo'<script>

            localStorage.removeItem("range");

            swal({
                  type: "success",
                  title: "The sale has been edited correctly",
                  showConfirmButton: true,
                  confirmButtonText: "Close"
                  }).then((result) => {
                            if (result.value) {

                            window.location = "sales";

                            }
                        })

            </script>';

        }

    }

}
```

above code is calling model edit-sales with data to update database

**This is model edit sales method**

[mdl:editsale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4L5r.png)

Comment: [don't post code/error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: sorry, its my first time posting here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put in last attribute all array `$value`, you only need to put only id `$value['id']`

```
$item1a = "sales";
$value1a = $getProduct["sales"] - $value["quantity"];

$newSales = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts, $item1a, $value1a, $value['id']);

$item1b = "stock";
$value1b = $value["quantity"] + $getProduct["stock"];

$stockNew = ProductsModel::mdlUpdateProduct($tableProducts, $item1b, $value1b, $value['id']);
```